# When implementing the VIPER pattern as described on objc.io, should care be taken to hide ReactiveCocoa as an implementation detail?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, binding, reactive-cocoa

The guide at http://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/#using-viper-to-build-modules was highly instructive and while none of this is groundbreaking, I thought it was well-done.

The author suggested that the glue between layers ought to be the `ReactiveCocoa` library. I downloaded this via `CocoaPods` but I am bit stuck. I cannot find an example of `ReactiveCocoa` + the VIPER pattern.

My question: should I a) make sure to *not* expose the `ReactiveCocoa` classes in my interfaces, b) expose them because of their relevance, or c) not worry about it?

Compare a and b examples of my `DetailsViewInteractorInputOutput.h`

```
/* Eg A */

@protocol DetailsViewInteractorInput<NSObject>

- (void)requestDetails;

@end

/* Eg B */

@protocol DetailsViewInteractorInput<NSObject>

- (RACSignal *)requestDetails;

@end

/* Eg A */

@protocol DetailsViewInteractorOutput<NSObject>

- (void)foundDetails:(MyDetails *)details;

@end

/* Eg B */

@protocol DetailsViewInteractorOutput<NSObject>

- (RACSignal *)foundDetails;

@end
```

Comment: did you make any headway on this approach? I'm also looking into this

Comment: any update on this? It would be great to see your implementation.

Comment: I made very little. I have it somewhere and I will post it if I can find it and its respectable but neither are likely... and you are not missing anything. What I learned was that it was not smart to try to shove this down the throat of the application, because it really didnt fit in some cases. I liked very much the aspect of unitizing the readers and writers, and I think it would be easier if there were a nice IoC container for Swift, but there isnt.